# Error when creating sqlContext in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Apache Spark and running it on Ipython notebook. 
I am trying to convert a regular dataframe to Spark DataFrame. For that I need sqlContext. When I use it i get an error. 
[image]

[image]

Error says:

```
IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':"
```

I have looked up multiple resources but am not able to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you send bit more error log?

Comment: @StackPointer I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

`SQLContext` *used to* be the entry point for the SQL functionality in Spark 1.x; in Spark 2 it has been replaced with `SparkSession` ([documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext)). So, here is the proper way to initialize Spark in version 2.2, which is the one you are using according to your screenshot:

```python
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
```

See the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) on Spark SQL for further usage examples.

Comment: @JohnConstantine It's because you are already running a Spark session. Restart your kernel and you should be fine

Comment: @JohnConstantine The error message is clear - there is a Spark context already running. Can't guess more since I don't know how you have initialized your pyspark session; if you do it interactively (most probable), try leaving out the `sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)` command or try `sc.stop()` first